# AS create a new project,code reports some error, but it can run normally

Tags: android, android-studio

[error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgqtz.png)

when I create a new project in Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 4 ,I create MainActivity by kotlin,code reports some error (introduced red), but it can run normally.

---

I' ve looked around and apparently I've got the choice between these solutions:

1. I try to Click File -> Invalidate Caches/Restar.Open the project again,not work.
2. I tyr to Build -> Clean project,Rebuild project.Not work,code reports some error
3. I try to Close my project, and in my project folder delete project/.idea and project/.gradle.Open the project again,not work.

It can run normally,but Look uncomfortable,I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Always try to avoid including screenshots of codes or errors. Copy-paste the error as code markdown. Please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how to create a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the latest and appropriate version for your `Gradle` and using the correct version of the initial in the Gradle. You can also invalidate your caches to ensure using the latest new data.
In some cases, upgrading your `SDK` is a way to fix the problem.

If not works, please share your error here to follow up.

Comment: I use this classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4",
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.0",
But The problem still exists